# Convert array of object to object with keys

Tags: javascript

say I have an array :

```
[ { name: 'A', count: 100 }, { name: 'B', count: 200 } ]
```

how can I get an object :

```
{ A : 100, B : 200 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try utilizing `Array.prototype.forEach()` to iterate properties , values of array , set properties of new object to properties , values of input array

```
var arr = [ { name: 'A', count: 100 }, { name: 'B', count: 200 } ];
// create object 
var res = {};
// iterate `arr` , set property of `res` to `name` property of 
// object within `arr` , set value of `res[val.name]` to value
// of property `count` within `arr`
arr.forEach(function(val, key) {
  res[val.name] = val.count
});
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a great opportunity to practice using [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) (or *reduceRight*, depending on desired behaviour)

```
[{name: 'A', count: 100}, {name: 'B', count: 200}].reduceRight(
    function (o, e) {o[e.name] = e.count; return o;},
    {}
); // {B: 200, A: 100}
```

This could also be easily modified to become a summer,

```
o[e.name] = (o[e.name] || 0) + e.count;
```